# Judah ben Simeon Ashkenazi on reading the weekly lection

Tags: halacha, torah-study

[Judah ben Simeon Ashkenazi](https://turshulchanarukh.alhatorah.org/Dual/Ba%27er_Hetev/Orach_Chayyim/285.1#m7ecn6) makes the following remark in his commentary on *Orach Chayim*:

> ואיסור גדול להפסיק בקריאת שמו״ת בדיבור.

Is this an original idea or is Ashkenazi following an earlier authority here?

What is the reason for this prohibition?

Some rabbis cite Moshe ben Machir, who says

> ואם אפשר לו שלא יפסיק בה על שום דבר הוא טוב ויפה וכן ראיתי מדקדקים עושים כן וכן ראוי לכל בעל נפש לעשות כדי שתהא קריאתה בקבע ולא בעראי

Some rabbis cite [Samuel ben Joseph](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19331&st=&pgnum=147)'s עולת שבת, where the author says:

> כתבו חכמי מקובלים שלא להפסיק בקריאת שמו"ת בשום דבר רק יקרא הכל בפעם אחת במעמד אחד ויש טעם נכון וכמוס לדבר זה

Unlike Ashkenazi, Moshe ben Machir and Samuel ben Joseph do not describe this practice as a prohibition but as a recommendation (Moshe) or a mystical concern (Samuel).

[I.M. Kagan](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=60388&st=&pgnum=132) suggests that what Ashkenazi really meant was that it is forbidden to interrupt in the middle of a topic (באמצע ענינא), but even if this is true, the question remains whence came this prohibition, who first mentioned it and what is the underlying reason.

Comment: From the context, he is clearly batting himself on the kabbalistic concern

Comment: @רבותמחשבות  I assume you are referring to Ashkenazi rather than the other rabbis. Kagan seems to think that Ashkenazi has a non-kabbalah concern here, but perhaps there is room for another view.

Comment: I am indeed referring only to Rabbi Ashkenazi. (Also, I believe the surname of Rabbi Kagan is actually Poupko.)

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Y.M. Kagan's surname was indeed Poupko, but he is better known by Kagan, apparently a Russianized version of כהן. I generally use the Wikipedia form of famous people's names.

Answer (score 1):

The [Kaf Hachayim](https://turshulchanarukh.alhatorah.org/Dual/Kaf_HaChayyim/Orach_Chayyim/285.1#m7ecn6) (paragraph 15) writes

> טו) וכתבו חכמי המקובלים שלא להפסיק בקריאת שמו״ת בשום דבר רק יקרא הכל בפעם אחת במעמד אחד ויש טעם נכון וכמוס בדבר זה. עו״ת או׳ ב׳ א״ר או׳ ב׳. מיהו אם הוא צמא למים הרבה מותר להפסיק בתוך הפרשה לשתות ולברך תחלה וסוף. לב חיים ח״ג סי׳ כ״ג. ועוד עיין לקמן או׳ ל״ב

In other words, the reason is kabbalistic. In paragraph 32 he shares some of the reasoning, but it is beyond my ability to really explain it.